# How to render array passed to sub element in React JS?

Tags: arrays, render, reactjs

I have simple example with JSON that has array in it.
It is loaded with ajax:

```
  {somekey: "value1", somekey2: "value2", belongsto: ["me","you"]}
```

I can render it by for example:

```
   <div>
          belongsto:  {this.state.data.belongsto}
   </div>
```

But I would love to render it as list in subcomponent, so I am trying:

```
    <Uli data={this.state.data.belongsto}/>
```

as:

```
    var Uli = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
        <ul className="Uli">
        {
          this.props.data.map(function(value) {
          return <li key={value}>{value}</li>
          })
        }
       </ul>
     )
    }
    });
```

And that gives me:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

How this should be achieved?

Comment: Do you have a `getInitialState` with an empty `belongsto` array?

Comment: `data` is likely empty the first time if you're loading the data asynchronously. If you just added `var data = this.props.data || []` to the `render`, ... and that works, then it was likely the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are loading your json data through AJAX asynchronously, and hence `belongsto` is `undefined` until you'll got the response from the server.

There are several solutions to solve this:

1. Add `getDefaultProps` method to your ULi component.

   ```
   var Uli = React.createClass({
       getDefaultProps() {
           return {
               data: []
           }
       },
       render: function() {
           return (
               <ul className="Uli">
               {this.props.data.map(function(value) {
                   return <li key={value}>{value}</li>
               })}
               </ul>
           )
       }
   });
   ```
2. Use `||` operator:

   ```
   <ul className="Uli">
       {(this.props.data || []).map(function(value) {
           return <li key={value}>{value}</li>
       })}
   </ul>
   ```
3. Prevent `ULi` rendering, if does not `belongsto` is `undefined`:

   ```
   {this.state.data.belongsto && <Uli data={this.state.data.belongsto}/>}
   ```

Comment: So, I want with the first one and it works fine in firefox :-), that’s great for me. I have just changed it into `  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return { data: []  }
  },` (Of course, without understanding)

Comment: Is there "a proper one" option to chose from four answer?